# How can I find the target of a symbolic link using VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, symlink

How can I find if a given file is a symbolic link? And once I know that it is, how can I get the target its pointing to? I'm using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/ReparsePointID.aspx
Go through this, I tried it and it works. It is written in C# and can be easily convertded into VB

Answer (score 0):

You use the [IShellLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774950%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface.

An example of using it in VB.Net is [here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=152821). While this example shows creating shortcuts, you can use it to see how to use IShellLink from within VB.Net code.

Comment: And I think the example code you have referenced is not working for symbolic links. Please share some example code for symbolic link.

Answer (score 0):

Link:
How do I get information about the target of a symbolic link?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/02/12/9962359.aspx

> ...
>
> Okay, great, so now I know I have a
>   symbolic link, but what if I want
>   information about the link target? For
>   example, I want to know the size of
>   the link target, its last-modified
>   time, and its name.
>
> To do this, you open the symbolic
>   link. The I/O manager dereferences the
>   symbolic link and gives you a handle
>   to the link destination. You can then
>   call functions like GetFileSize,
>   GetFileInformationByHandleEx, or
>   GetFinalPathNameByHandle to obtain
>   information about the symbolic link
>   target.
>
> ...